# How to retrieve data from Firebase store it in TextView object in Swift code given below?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is my code. I am trying to retrieve data stored in politics table of firebase and want to store it in textview object of uitextview class in Swift. `create()` function stores data in Firebase table.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class PoliticsNewsViewController: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var Image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    var ref:FIRDatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Retrieval and insertion must done here currently
         create()
    }

    func create()
    {
        //let date="9 feb 2017"
        let text="Sidhu joins congress"
        let aapNews="Arvind kejriwal now in race of wining wining punjab elections as he is gaining 70% seats in punjab"
        let BJPNews="BJP sufeers major blow in punjab due to demonatization gaining only 40 seats"
        ref=FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        ref.child("Politics News Table").childByAutoId().setValue(["Text" : text,"AAP news" : aapNews,"BJP News" : BJPNews])
    }
```

Comment: What's your question? What issue are you having with your code? [Edit] your question with relevant details.

Comment: my question is how should I fetch data from firebase and store it in textview object of uitextview in swift as I want to show data in uitextview panel of my app

Comment: As I said, [edit] your question with relevant details.

Comment: now is it fine?? rmaddy

Comment: Slightly better but you still haven't explained what problem you are having. You just posted a vague requirement and a bunch of code.

Comment: The answer provided is correct but a few things that may help. Firebase doesn't have tables or schema (SQL). It's a JSON structure with parent and child nodes. Secondly if there is more than one child (as in this case) it will be a dictionary and you access that Dictionary by casting the snapshot.value to a dict. Keep in mind that if the snapshot contains several child nodes, each will be it's own snapshot and it's value (may be) a dict as well. Once the value is cast to a Dictionary, you can access the child nodes by let a = dict["field"] as! String (for example)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the data from firebase, you should use the `observe` method from the firebase reference. You provide it a closure, and when to listen, and it will be called everytime the data in the database changes.

Look at this example

```
ref.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
        guard let info = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject], let textToShow = info["Text"] as? String else {
            return
        }
        // The snapshot is an object from firebase that is castable to
        // an array
        // The info array contains the information that you database has 
        // under the child that your reference has

        textView.text = textToShow
        //Here the textView has updated the text
    })
```

For further information,like the eventTypes that are avaialable, look in the following link:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data

Comment: ok.one query. what role is performed by as?[String:Anyobject] ??

Comment: Firebase returns a snapshot, which is of the class FIRSnapshot, which is not really usable. 

The thing is that the class can be represented also as a dictionary, which makes it really easier to get its info, just by getting its values from a key.

What I'm doing there is casting the FIRSnapshot class to the dictionary, of type [String:Anyobject], with the as? operator. I'm using the as? operator and not the as! operator in order to not force downcast

Comment: @FedericoOjeda Good answer but the word *callback* should actually be *closure*. Also a FIRDataSnapshot is highly usable in many situations as it not only contains the key of the node but also it's value. AND you can iterate over it to retrieve child data. Finally what is represented by the snapshots value may NOT always be a dictionary; it could be a string, bool or array as well. It's a very powerful class.

Comment: @Jay Really good points there.It's true, its actually a closure, not a callback. Also, the FIRDataSnapshot point is totally right, it's really powerful. What I thought is that for this case, the cast to the dictionary is really useful. Thanks! I'll make the updates

Comment: guys i am still not getting it :-(. Anyone know any Firebase video tutorial in which every concept is explained.? ALSO WHAT value get inserted in info["text"] ??

Comment: I don' t know about any video actually, the best place to learn it is the firebase documentation in the link in the answer. It covers almost every case. About the info["text"] it was just an example. If your reference to the dabatase was pointing to a node in the json like this { "text": "Hello!", "number": 5 }, for example, info["text"] would return "Hello!".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more verbose answer to go along with the correct answer that may help.

Assume we have a social media app with posts. Here's the posts node

```
posts
  -Yiias9j9asd
    post: "a post about stuff"
    date: "20170209"
  -Yinjiisidd
    post: "another post about stuff"
    date: "20170210"
```

and then the code to read in all the posts and print them to the log

```
let postsRef = ref.child("posts")
postsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for snap in snapshot.children {
        let postKey = postSnap.key //the key of each post
        let postSnap = snap as! FIRDataSnapshot //the child data snapshot
        let postDict = postSnap.value as! [String:AnyObject] //child data dict

        let post = postDict["post"] as! String
        let date = postDict["date"] as! String
        print("postKey: \(postKey) post: \(post)  date: \(date)")
        //now that you have the data, you can add it to a textView
        // textView.text = post for example
     }
})
```

Note that the node key names, like Yiias9j9asd are created with childByAutoId and is generally the recommended way to have Firebase create discreet node names.